# How can I create a new variable in Julia using an ifelse condition dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I want to create a new variable (nota) using an if-else function with the `transform!` function from the `DataFrames` package.

Here is my code:

```
using DataFrames
datos = DataFrame(nombre =["ANGELICA","BRENDA","LILIANA","MARCO","FABIAN","MAURICIO"],
    grupo = ["A","A","B","B","C","C"],
    puntaje = [10,9,8,8,9,7]);
transform!(datos, :puntaje => ifelse(datos[datos.puntaje .< 9,:],"Suficiente","Excelente") => :nota)
```

but this error displays:

```
ERROR: TypeError: non-boolean (BitVector) used in boolean context

Stacktrace:

[1] top-level scope

  @ REPL[23]:1
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You are mixing `ByRow` with normal transform which is by column
2. You can't mutate type of `puntaje` column

You probably want to do this:

```
julia> datos.puntaje = ifelse.(datos.puntaje .< 9, "Suficiente", "Excelente")
6-element Vector{String}:
 "Excelente"
 "Excelente"
 "Suficiente"
 "Suficiente"
 "Excelente"
 "Suficiente"

julia> datos
6×3 DataFrame
 Row │ nombre    grupo   puntaje    
     │ String    String  String     
─────┼──────────────────────────────
   1 │ ANGELICA  A       Excelente
   2 │ BRENDA    A       Excelente
   3 │ LILIANA   B       Suficiente
   4 │ MARCO     B       Suficiente
   5 │ FABIAN    C       Excelente
   6 │ MAURICIO  C       Suficiente
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. In fact, I want to create a new variable `datos.nota = ifelse.(datos.puntaje .< 9, "Suficiente", "Excelente")`

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer using `transform!`, two syntaxes that work are:

```
julia> datos = DataFrame(nombre =["ANGELICA","BRENDA","LILIANA","MARCO","FABIAN","MAURICIO"],
           grupo = ["A","A","B","B","C","C"],
           puntaje = [10,9,8,8,9,7]);

julia> transform!(datos, :puntaje => (p -> ifelse.(p .< 9, "Suficiente", "Excelente")) => :nota)
6×4 DataFrame
 Row │ nombre    grupo   puntaje  nota       
     │ String    String  Int64    String     
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ ANGELICA  A            10  Excelente
   2 │ BRENDA    A             9  Excelente
   3 │ LILIANA   B             8  Suficiente
   4 │ MARCO     B             8  Suficiente
   5 │ FABIAN    C             9  Excelente
   6 │ MAURICIO  C             7  Suficiente

julia> transform!(datos, :puntaje => ByRow(p -> ifelse(p < 9, "Suficiente", "Excelente")) => :nota)
6×4 DataFrame
 Row │ nombre    grupo   puntaje  nota       
     │ String    String  Int64    String     
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ ANGELICA  A            10  Excelente
   2 │ BRENDA    A             9  Excelente
   3 │ LILIANA   B             8  Suficiente
   4 │ MARCO     B             8  Suficiente
   5 │ FABIAN    C             9  Excelente
   6 │ MAURICIO  C             7  Suficiente
```